# Sandbox mode disabled, but app not visible to all

Tags: facebook, sandbox

I created an app for a page tab and enabled sandbox mode to test it before it went live. I added a couple of test users to the app so they could test and it was all working as expected.

I've now disabled sandbox mode for the app, but the app is **not** visible to all and only the previously added test users can see it. The app icon and link appears at the top of the page but when clicked it just redirects back to the same page.

The sandbox mode setting is definitely showing as Disabled, and if I had a new test user they can then see the app!

I've also tested this same process with a different app and have had the same problem.

Has anyone encountered this before, or know of any issues with Facebook at the moment that could cause this?

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be a bug - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/324925350903610?browse=search_4f7d5dd2772208094229552.

Comment: If anyone has the same problem, recreating the app and not putting it in sandbox mode seems to get round it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well.  I followed Dan Som's advice and recreated the app without enabling sandbox mode.  Sure enough, my app was visible.

Then I started modifying the settings to match my old app.  Afterwards, my new app was no longer visible.  I realized that one of the settings I toggled/enabled prevented my new app from being visible to non-testers/developers.

That setting was; in my case, `Age Restrictions`.  I had it set to `People 18 and older` even though it did not have to be.  I set it back to the default setting `Anyone (13+)` and my app was visible again.  I suspect your app requires approval from Facebook if you have such an age restriction.

You can change it in `Settings | Advanced | App Restrictions`.

If you or anyone is still encountering this issue- it's worth a look.